# tf.fold vs tf.scan vs tf.map_fn

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, parallel-processing, neural-network, computer-vision

I am confused with the implementation of the following functions in TensorFlow, I am currently using tf.map_fn to create a higher-order tensor unpacked from multiple objects detected in a Multi-Object Tracker.

```
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None])

    samples_flat = tf.map_fn(lambda samples: tf.layers.flatten(samples), input, dtype=tf.float32)



    W4 = tf.scan(lambda x: tf.get_variable('fc4/kernel', shape=(1024, 512),
                         initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()), samples_flat)

    b4 = tf.get_variable('fc4/bias', shape=512, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    fc4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(samples_flat, W4), b4)
    fc4 = tf.nn.relu(fc4)



    W5 = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.get_variable('fc5/kernel', shape=(512, 512),
                                             initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()), fc4)

    b5 = tf.get_variable('fc5/bias', shape=512, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    fc5 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc4, W5), b5)
    fc5 = tf.nn.relu(fc5)



    W6 = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.get_variable('fc6/kernel', shape=(512, 2),
                                             initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), fc5)

    b6 = tf.get_variable('fc6/bias', shape=2, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    fc6 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc5, W6), b6)
```

Is there an easier way to implement everything under one function and calculate loss and apply gradients instead of using these functions several times?